# I don't see the Plugins options in my QGIS 2.18

Tags: qgis, plugins

[image]I have installed QGIS 2.18 but i do not see the Plugins tab on the toolbar menu. How can i access it?

Comment: can you add an image? and did you try to click right on a panel and see if you can add it with this context menu?

Comment: I HAVE ADDED A SCREENSHOT

Comment: You are opening GRASS not QGIS.

Comment: I've voted for close as the error can not be reproduced

Answer (score 5):

You are opening GRASS not QGIS. Plugin menu is available in QGIS:

[image]